# Making email as primary key is bad idea?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am making an application in which users may create their accounts. I make user email as primary key in user's table. Is this technique is really bad technique? Should I create auto increment integer as primary key?

Comment: I'd use an int as primary key and put a unique index on the email column.

Comment: It's not a good idea... People change a-mail addresses once in a while.

Comment: Are users never allowed to change which email address is associated with their account?

Comment: I would suggest use of incremental int or guid as primary key and e-mail as unique index. This will be safer, easier and more convenient.

Comment: Very bad idea, the speed of cross table lookups would decrease dramatically I'd imagine

Comment: Also foreign key columns will make a lot of overloads, because of data type...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is a terrible idea. An email is something long (so your key is longer than necessary), and it isn't immutable. I've changed at least three emails in the last ten years (providers closed).

Comment: thank you I got your point.

Comment: I think that the main problem with email addresses as primary key is that you also have them as foreign-key, everyhwere.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes. Clearly if you have a single table in the DB then you can use the email as a primary key :) But it would be a very very simple DB